# BLE nordic Secure DFU

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

How to implement Secure DFU using nordic DFU sdk in android application?

I am using nordic DFU sdk for Firmware update.It is work with normal DFU mode. But when I'm trying with Secure DFU then connection failed. I am use following code in android application.

// Android app code //

```
 new DfuServiceInitiator(Device MacAddress)
                        .setKeepBond(true)
                        .setDisableNotification(true)
                        .setZip(mFileStreamUri, mFileStreamUri.getPath())
                        .start(this, DFUService.class);
```

I got this kind of log.

// log //

```
 I/DfuBaseService: Connecting to the device...
 D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: CA:E1:0D:C1:02:F1, auto: false
 D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
 D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=37c55721-972b-4bf2-b0d0-034e92423ca6
 D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7
 D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=7 device=CA:E1:0D:C1:
 E/DfuBaseService: Connection state change error: 133 newState: 0
 E/DfuBaseService: Device got disconnected before service discovery finished
 D/BluetoothGatt: refresh() - device: CA:E1:0D:C1:02:F1
 I/DfuBaseService: Refreshing result: true
 I/DfuBaseService: Cleaning up...
 D/BluetoothGatt: close()
 D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=7
 E/radiance.smart.toilet.Activity.ConnectionActivity: onError: 4096
 E/radiance.smart.toilet.Activity.ConnectionActivity: errorType: 0
 E/radiance.smart.toilet.Activity.ConnectionActivity: message: DFU DEVICE DISCONNECTED
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Solve issue just add line in my android app code.

**.setUnsafeExperimentalButtonlessServiceInSecureDfuEnabled(true)**

Comment: I get the same error on a Huawei Android 7.0 phone, otherwise with a General Mobile android 7.0 everything works perfectly